# Maui XAML 'ImageSource.FromStream' remains null?

Tags: xaml, maui, imagesource

Bit new to Maui, trying to update an ImageSource at runtime.
I've been searching for quite a few hours now. Any help is welcome. The code runs without any errors, yet the 'Source' of the Image object remains 'null' (stream is ok)

**eventArgs.Frame** => System.Drawing.Bitmap

**camcap** => `<Image x:Name="camcap"/>`

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                eventArgs.Frame.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => this.camcap.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream));
            }
```

Comment: The Stream should be rewound: `stream.Position = 0;`

Comment: useful but this made no difference :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `OnAppearing()` method to update an ImageSource at runtime. Here is the document about the [OnAppearing() method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.page.onappearing?view=net-maui-8.0) you can refer to.

```
   protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
    
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
        eventArgs.Frame.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        camcap.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => { return stream; });
    
       
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, yet this gave no difference, having an extra error now on the last line of code that might be usefull:  ```` Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in WinRT.Runtime.dll
An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in WinRT.Runtime.dll but was not handled in user code ````